# Ruby on Rails: should all my ActiveRecord callback methods be private?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

I have an ActiveRecord model which has some callbacks and custom validations I want to test. It means, that I have to make all of them public. Is that a good practice or is there a better solution in this case?

Examples of the methods I want to test:

```
  def before_validation
    original.edit(self) if original
  end

  validate :unique?, on: :create

  def unique?
    return true if original.blank?
    errors.add(:base, 'The entry already exists')
    false
   end
```

In other words:

1. If I want to test "before_validation" method, do I have to make it public and call test_object.before_validation directly in my model Rspec file?
2. If I want to test not only, that custom validation method unique?() is called on validation, but also, the method itself, do I have to make the unique?() public as well?

The problem is, that neither of these methods I am using outside my of model (so they they should be private), but how could I test without making them public?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to get caught up in testing implementation, but this is a good candidate for testing behaviour.

Ask yourself, what is your before validation really doing? Then make yourself a test that, given certain inputs, you'll get certain outputs if and only if your before validation works.

As a simple example, imagine you have a user model with a simple `name` attribute, and you have a before_validation that simply does:

```
name = "Auto-generated name." if name.blank?
```

Then you could write a test for it like this:

```
it "gets an auto-generated name if none is specified." do
    user = User.create!
    user.name.should eq "Auto-generated name."
end

it "does not get an auto-generated name if one is specified." do
    user = User.create!(:name => "Test Name")
    user.name.should eq "Test Name"
end
```

So as you can see, this test does test the validation, but it doesn't need it to be public, because you're just testing the behaviour of it. The same goes for your `unique?` method. Give it certain inputs and test the behaviour, without having to care about which specific method was used or any other implementation details.